# Usage of \caption command in converting LaTeX files to HTML using tex4ht

Tags: captions, conversion, tex4ht

Hi I'm new to LateX and Tex4ht. So please bear with my inexperience.

I am required to convert LaTeX source files into HTML (I further require to compile them into .chm files; I have decided to first work on the HTML output and then worry about the chm part)

My source includes pictures and I have used the `\caption` command to provide the necessary captions. The MWE is:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{figs/figure1.png}
 \end{center}
 \caption{Startup Screen}
\end{figure}
```

On running the `pdflatex` command from command prompt I get accurate `.pdf` files but when I run the `htlatex` command the caption is skewed to the left of the `.html` formed.

Any help would be great..!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure appearance with css instructions in the custom config file.

Try this, name the file `myconf.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.caption{text-align:center;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Important line is `\Css{div.caption ...}` whis is css instruction to center the text, `div.caption` is element generated by `tex4ht` for `\caption` commands.

Now compile your file with

```
htlatex filename "myconf"
```

and captions should be centered

Comment: So I'm not allowed to vote up as yet! Worked like a charm thanks :)

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to do the same thing with Tables. I assumed that this same configuration file should work since I am again having trouble with aligning the Table Captions to the center; it does not seem to work for some reason.

Any suggestions on how I can over this?

thanks :)

Comment: @AnirudhJ it would be best if you could post it as new question with complete example, probably you will need to add more configurations for tables